# Automatic inheritance of all base class attributes

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance

I want to create a class that has two characteristics:

- Inherits a base class (all attributes and methods) automatically
- Takes an object of that base class as an argument.

I want these two characteristics because I want to automatically inherit all the attributes and methods of the previous object (base class object) without having to do something like use the `__init__` method since this will cause recalculation of the already computed initialization. And since there will be a lot of methods and attributes I don't think its good practice to do it manually.

My idea of the code would look something like this.

```
class BaseClass(object):
     def __init__(self, name, date):
         self.name = name
         self.date = date

     def get_name_date(self):
         self.name_date = self.name +self.date

class UpperClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.date_name = self.date + self.name
```

I know the code above will not work and I dont want to do something like:

```
class UpperClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(BaseClass, self).__init__(name, date)
        self.date_name = self.date + self.name
```

Cause this will re-do calculations I already have.
Maybe inheritance is not what I'm looking for, any pointers?

Comment: "since this will cause recalculation of the already computed initialization" - why do you think it would do that? It sounds like you've misunderstood how `__init__` works.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't make `date_name` an attribute of `BaseClass`?

Comment: If these calculation results are different from instance to instance, it can't be helped: these calculations will need to be done on every instantiation. If the results are always the same, just define them as class attributes instance of instance attributes.

Comment: @user2357112 will it not recalculate?

Comment: @ThmeiEsi is just an example but the main reason is that I'm designing a very 'chronological' process so I want to break it down into several classes. That's why I don't define the different methods in the base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name, date):
        self.name = name
        self.date = date

    def get_name_date(self):
        self.name_date = self.name +self.date

class UpperClass:
    def __init__(self, baseobject):
        self.baseobject = baseobject
        self.date_name = baseobject.date + baseobject.name

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(self.baseobject, item)

o1 = BaseClass('thmei', 'may')
o2 = UpperClass(o1)

print(o1.date) # may
print(o2.date) # may
print(o2.date_name) # maythmei
```

Comment: Yes! this looks like something I was looking for.

Actually if I define yet another method inside UpperClass and then I try to access it by doing `o2.method2()` it won't crash, although in my mind it should try to look into `self.baseobject.method2()`. Why is it working?

Comment: `__getattr__` is only called if the attribute does not exist in the object. So calling `o2.method2()` never calls `__getattr__` because the method exists in the object already.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Comment: Not that this is **not** inheritance. `UpperClass` instances _have_ an instance of a `BaseClass` object saved in one of their attributes.

Comment: Yes, OP says he does not know if inheritance is the correct way to do it. My answer simply takes another approach.

Comment: hey @ThmeiEsi will this approach work if I try to acces two different objects?
`class Summary:
 def __init__(self, objA, objB):
  self.objA = objA
  self.objB = objB
     
     def __getattr__(self, item):
         return getattr(self.objA, item)

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(self.objB, item)`

Comment: If you put it in a loop of try/except blocks you could get something working.